# RaspberryPi3B does connect to wlan but not to ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, internet

After a system update and reboot the Raspberry Pi stopped working on ethernet. When I run the command ifconfig I have the output returned for ethernet interface

Comment: Its possible the switch the Pi has been plugged into has got the line speed into a mixed state (PI at one speed / Switch at another).  Have you tried a full power off / on (with at least 10 seconds between)?

Comment: What operating system do you use? Raspbian Buster? What exactly were the commands you have used for update? Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/110993/edit) your question and add the information and the output of this commands to it: `ip addr`, `ip route` and `host google.com`.

Comment: I was forced to reinstall a fresh OS raspbian buster.Reason why it was the correct thing to do because the newer installation is flawless I could configure a flawless static IP connection via ethernet and wifi.The previous one was rigged as the internet interface was clearly not well installed (as matter of fact the default option was broken).The hardware specification is almost identical except for the new SD card of 32gb rather than 8gb. When I went through the installation I remember that the first time I accidentally skipped the awaiting for the end of the installation and reboot.shameonme

Comment: I was running omv 5 on top of raspbian buster

Comment: Honestly it happened again. I do not know what is the cause but internet configuration with OMV5 is just messed up (both buster and buster lite). *I do not know why but I managed to fix it today taking the ethernet cable out and putting it into my flawless laptop, and back to the raspberry pi*, is this possible that this triggered something?. Now even after reboots it seems to work. I have installed qbittorrent rather than transmission as previously configured. Of course on debian gui desktop the ethernet icon and configuration is crossed out and just useless as not reliable anymore.